# jQuery datepicker return on Ajax. Should I eval()?

Tags: jquery, eval

I'm creating a form builder using Zend_Framework and jQuery. I've run into a hypothetical question, that I would like an answer to.

While building a form, the Ajax returns an element, that should be a datepicker. I know, that I can turn the input into a datepicker by using a default class, like `.calendar` and to use `livequery()` to re-bind the events to these inputs.

Now the problem arises when I need the datepickers to have different settings. For an example,

1. A datepicker that allows all dates above 20/10/2010
2. A datepicker that allows only sundays to be selected.

As far as I can tell, I have only 1 way to approach this problem:

**Load the jQuery code it requires via Ajax, and then `eval()` it.**

***Is this the right way to do this, and what could be the pitfalls of this, if I know that the code is properly sanitized?***

If anyone can provide some better solution, please, do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have appended the datepicker element to the document, you should be able to create a new call on it. This would mean that every time you used the ajax it would create a new datepicker instance, but if you are changing the settings I'm pretty sure that's the only *safe* way to go about it. Add the new datepicker options to you success handler and go from there.

Comment: So, You're saying I should go with `eval()`?

Comment: You shouldn't need to eval anything. But are you returning the javascript you need to use for the datepicker? If at all possible I would try to avoid this and set the correct options based on the ajax response rather than send through the ajax response

Comment: I ended up passing back the data needed to create the element via meta-data. Worked out great and without eval.